# Netbeans don't refresh php code completion

Tags: php, netbeans, code-completion

I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1 and php code completion hints don't see the new code I modified, it only refresh at restart.

For example if I add a constant to a class, it don't appear in the code completion, but if I restart nb, then it appears.

Any fix or way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created again the project and moved the files to the new one. Now seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with more recent versions of Netbeans (7.x). Code completion didn't display changes made in a coding session. I had to rescan the project manually every time I added new methods or properties in a class. Creating a new project and clearing the cache didn't work for me. So I tried updating my Java runtime and that did the trick.

You may also have to tell Netbeans which JRE to use if you're having multiple versions of java installed. Go to {NetbeansDirectory}/etc/ and edit the file netbeans.conf, change the netbeans_jdkhome variable to get something like the following : netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7".

Comment: how do you rescan project manually? how do you clear the netbeans cache? I'm getting this bug in java and netbeans 7.3...